# Convert SAS code to Pandas equivalent for groupby.first() and retain function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sas

I have SAS code i need to convert into python pandas.

```
   data df1;
   set df;
       by id;
       retain flag_final;
       if first.id then do;
          if flag eq 0 then flag_final=flag;
          else flag_final=.;
       end;
       else do;
          flag_final=flag_final;
   run;
```

I tried something like this in pandas but its not working i mean am not able to put if else condition into my merge clause. If some one has better idea how to get it done it would be very helpful

```
  df_temp=df[['id','flag']]
  df1= df.merge(df_temp.groupby('id').first().reset_index(), on='id').rename(
columns={'flag_x':'flag', 'flag_y':'flag_final'})
```

Note: Even i am not able to understand obove SAS code. So can not put any example input and output dataset. If some knows SAS well can help me to understand it then might be possible i can convert it into pandas. Or you have some approach please suggest.

Edit: Adding input and output dataset:

Input Dataframe:

```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np

 df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,2,1,2,2,3,3,4,3,3,4,4,4], 'flag': [np.nan,0,1,'p','q',0,"",2,0,'r',np.nan,0,1,np.nan]})
 df=df.sort_values('id')

  id      flag

  1         NaN
  1         0
  1         p
  2         1
  2         q
  2         0
  3         ""
  3         2
  3         r
  3         NaN
  4         0
  4         0
  4         1
  4        NaN
```

Output dataset:

```
  id      flag     flag_final

  1         NaN     .
  1         0       .
  1         p       .
  2         1       .
  2         q       .
  2         0       .   
  3         ""      .
  3         2       .
  3         r       .
  3         NaN     .
  4         0       0
  4         0       0
  4         1       0
  4        NaN      0
```

I tried like this but its not working:

```
df=df.sort_values('id')
df.loc[:,'flag_final']=df
df['flag_final']=np.where(df['id'].first,np.where(df['flag'].iloc[0]==0,df['flag'],'.'),np.nan)
```

Comment: Code conversion is not on topic here.

Comment: does any one get how to get above result ?

Comment: Repeating - code conversion is not on topic here.

Comment: @joe its just not a code conversion its a scenario which i am trying to implement in pandas. i have given input and output dataset. If any one can help it would be great ... also will get one idea to implement such logic in pandas i believe.

Comment: Also anyone will write some condition or logic to get help ..that needs to be converted in code. In my case i have put my conditions as SAS code

Comment: Asking code written for you is no better. This is a help site not a do your work site. Correct way to do this is try and solve the problem, then if it fails post what didn't work and ask that.

Comment: Your last line is good, but define not working. Give what is not working and how.

Answer (score 2):

Breaking down line-by-line:

```
 data df1;
   set df;
```

Create a new data set called `df1`, and read the values from `df` into it row-by-row.

```
by id;
```

When reading `df` row-by-row, read it in ordered by the variable `id`.

```
retain flag_final;
```

When reading a new row, initialize `flag_final` as the last value it was given.

```
if first.id then do;
```

If it's the first ID in the ordered block of IDs, do some functions.

```
if flag eq 0 then flag_final = flag;
    else flag_final = .;
end;
```

If the variable `flag` is 0, then make the variable `flag_final` take the value of `flag`. Otherwise, make the variable `flag_final` a missing value.

```
else do;
    flag_final = flag_final;
end;
```

If it's not the first value of `ID` in the group, set the value of `flag_final` to itself.

```
new_col = id;
```

Create a new variable called `new_col` that takes the value of `id`.

```
run;
```

The end of the data step.

Comment: i don't understand how first.id could be false .. for any id we will get some record or null or empty ... so if i understand correctly if for that id we get first record it should copy the same record for all below same ids. so if first.id is null it will copy null .... where the else condition comes into picture ?

Comment: first. refers to the first observation in a group of variables. first. will be 1 if it's the first observation within that group, and last. will be 1 if it's the last observation within that group. Within that group, all observations in-between produce 0 for first. and last.

Comment: Thanks bit clear now.... okay now can help me to write else condition in pandas. it seems whatever code i have tried is only for if condition not for else condition..... as  if first.id is not true it means with in that group all observations should produce 0 now in that case how i can assign any variable in pandas ?

Comment: Unfortunately that is beyond my expertise. I have not written any code in Pandas before.

Comment: Underrated Answer +1

Answer (score 1):

Here You go:

```
dfy = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,2,1,2,2,3,3,4,3,3,4,4,4], 'flag': [np.nan,0,1,'p','q',0,"",2,0,'r',np.nan,0,1,np.nan]})
dfy["flag_final"] = np.nan
def func1(group):
    if group.flag.values[0] == 0:
        group.flag_final.values[0] = "0"
    else:
        group.flag_final.values[0] = "1"
    return group

dfy.sort_values('id', inplace=True)
dfy = dfy.groupby(['id']).apply(func1).fillna(method='ffill')
dfy["flag_final"] = dfy["flag_final"].map({0:0, 1:"." })
```

I am trying to figure out how to add an empty object column with NaN Values so that I can eliminate the last line by just changing the "1" in function func1 to "."